# Why this .js code doesn't open the browser when i run it?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nightmare

I want to open the website via this code and it doesn't work. What's the problem? No errors are shown.

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var d = Nightmare({show:true});

d.goto('https://duckduckgo.com').wait(3000).end().then(result => {});
```

Comment: I haven't tested this out myself but try rewriting your last line as d.goto('https://duckduckgo.com').wait(3000).end().then( (result) => {}); - Note that I put the "result" in parantheses. Does that fix the issue?

Comment: @vivianyoung that doesn't change what the code does.

Comment: You need to call `d.show` also 300 ms is a small amount of time for a browser to be opened and show a page.